# Image as plane or hdri?

Tags: image, hdri

Ok so how do i go from this.

[image]

To something like this.

[image]

Are they using a HDRI or an image as a plane or doing that in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is both.

A HDRI (High Dynamic Range Image) is an image used to represent the environment in your scene. It is used to provide lighting and background imagery in all directions. HDRI images are provided in **.exr** format.

A HDRI is used in the World settings in the Shader editor. It is not used as part of the material for an object in your scene (such as a plane).

In your sample image above, the foliage, sky, ground etc. **in the background** is likely a HDRI image.

The motorbike could be a plane with an image of a motorbike, placed in a scene with the HDRI. The grass in the foreground would also be a 'real' object (not part of the HDRI).

Let's try to make something similar.
Note, this example will by for Cycles rendering engine. To get this working with Eevee will require a few additional steps.

We'll start with the HDRI.
I've downloaded a free HDRI from [PolyHaven](https://polyhaven.com): https://polyhaven.com/a/clarens_night_02

We'll use this HDRI to light our scene, and provide a background:

- Starting with a new project, let's make sure Cycles is selected

[image]

- Select the 'Shading' workspace tab

[image]

- Hover your mouse in the 3D Viewport and press 'Z' to change to Rendered View
- In the Shader editor (bottom window), set the Shader type to World

[image]

This will allow use to make changes to the environment lighting.
By default, there is a Background node set to a grey color. This is what gives us the grey environment lighting in Rendered View. You can experiment by changing the color of the Background node.

In order to use our HDRI, we need to add some nodes.

- In the Shader editor workspace, press Shift+A and add a Texture > Environment Texture node

[image]

- Use this node to open the HDRI downloaded from PolyHaven
- Connect the Environment Texture node to the Color input of the Background node

You should now be able to see the HDRI in the Rendered View above. You can rotate your view around the screen and note that the HDRI is present on all sides.

It's important to note that the HDRI is not just a background image. It is also providing light in your scene. So the sky is providing some bluish light, the sun some orangish light, etc.

In order to adjust the position of our HDRI, we need two more nodes.

- In the Shader workspace, use Shift+A to add an Input > Texture Co-ordinate node, and a Vector > Mapping node.
- Connect the **Generated** output from the Texture Co-ordinate node into the **Vector** input of the Mapping node.
- Connect the Vector output from the Mapping node to the Vector input of the
  Environment Texture node.

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

You can now adjust the position, scale and rotation of your HDRI using the Mapping node. I would recommend only changing the Z rotation to begin with.

Now that we have our HDRI, we can move on to the Go-kart.

- Select the 'Modelling' workspace Tab.
- Press Shift+A > Image > Images as Planes and open the Go-kart image.
- Press 3 to go to side-view, and Zoom in to get a good look at the new plane object.
- Press Z to go to Rendered View

**Note: the HDRI will not show correctly while in an Orthographic view (such as side view). If you rotate your view slightly you will be able to see the HDRI**

Now we need to get rid of the white background on the Go-kart.

- Go back to the Shader workspace Tab, and adjust your view so you can see the Go-kart.

**Note: before working on materials, I strongly recommend enabling the Node Wrangler add-on. You can search online how to do this, it's very simple.**

**The Node Wrangler add-on gives us access to some very useful shortcuts when working on materials.**

- Change the Shader type from World back to Object

The image you provided does not have any transparency (alpha channel). It would be much better if it **did** have a transparent background, as we could use the Alpha output from the Texture node to add transparency to our material.

Instead, we will have to try to isolate the white areas of the image, and make them transparent.

- Start by removing the connection from the Texure node Alpha output to the Principled BSDF Alpha input. As our image does not contain an alpha channel, this connection is not doing anything.
- Next, add a Converter > Color Ramp. Connect the Color output from the Texture node to the Fac input of the Color Ramp. **Leave the connection between the Texture node and the Principled BSDF connected**

[image]

- **Node Wrangler required** Hold CTRL+Shift and left-click on the Color Ramp. This will allow us to preview the output from the Color Ramp.

As you can see, the Color Ramp convert the image to black & white:

[image]

We can move the two 'flags' on the color ramp to try to isolate the white areas. In the image below I have set the black flag to a position of .405 and the white flag to a position of .450:

[image]

We can now use this black and white image from the Color Ramp to determine which parts of our plane should be transparent.

- Use Shift+A to add a Mix Shader and a Transparent Shader, and add them to your node tree as follows:

[image]

- Plug the output from the Color Ramp into the Fac input of the Mix Shader:

[image]

- You will notice that part of our image is transparent, but it's the wrong way around. To fix this, simply swap the inputs on the Mix Shader:

[image]

As a final step, reduce the Roughness on the Principled BSDF to a low value (i.e. 0.05). You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Some final notes:

You will likely notice some spots under the tyres and front wing that do not look great. This is due to the shadows cast on the floor of the original image. Again, I would recommend using a better source image for a project like this, preferably one with a transparent background and no floor (shadows).

The material in it's current form could be dramatically improved by adding bump, applying different roughness to different parts of the material, defining which areas are/are not metallic, etc. This was just a quick demo to get you started.

I would not recommend this approach for major elements in a scene. I tend to use this approach to quickly add small details to my scene (for example, birds flying in the background).
You will always have limited results using this approach for large-scale objects in your scene. Because the plane image does not have any depth, it will not play correctly with lighting and shadows cast by other objects in your scene. This becomes quite obvious when looking at larger objects, but goes largely unnoticed for smaller, background objects.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Yes i would like an update, this is something i want to be able to do. Amazing community.

Comment: Thank you so much, i am worrking on it now.

Comment: No problem. If this helped to answer your question would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks!